# adding sequential values in list to target value

Tags: python

The idea is for each number to add the next sequential numbers to try to reach the target value. If for each starting value (for i...) if adding the next sequential numbers exceeds the target then i has failed and move onto the next.

I'm getting some values slipping through and some duplicating.

If the targets intentionally match the lists it works fine; I've noticed 13 throws up some strange behaviour.

```
def addToTarget (mylist, target):

  solutions_list = []

  for i in range(0,len(mylist)):

    #set base values
    total = mylist[i]
    counter = i 
    solutions = []


    solutions.append(total)

    if total == target:
        solutions_list.append(solutions) # first value matches immediately

    elif total > target:
        solutions_list.append([counter-1, "first value already too high"])

    elif counter == (len(mylist)):
        solutions_list.append("caught as final value ")

    while total < target and counter < (len(mylist)-1):
        counter +=1
        value = mylist[counter]
        total += value
        solutions.append(value)

        if total == target:
            solutions_list.append([counter, solutions])

        elif total > target:
            solutions_list.append([counter-1, "total > target during"])

        elif counter == (len(mylist)-1):
            solutions_list.append([counter-1, "total < target - came to end of list "])

        else : solutions_list.append([counter-1, "not sure but certian values seem to slip through"])

return solutions_list
```

---

```
mylist = [5, 5, 3, 10, 2, 8, 10]
solutions_list = []
test = answer(mylist, 13)

for i in test : print(i)
```

Comment: can you add your expected output ?

Comment: in terms of the list stated and the target of 13 i would expect     answers = [[5,5,3], fail, [3,10], fail, fail, fail, fail]

Comment: i've added the counter number to the output to see , in this case there are multiple entries for entry at index 2, none at index 0 and 1 and double for index 5. I've tried tracking the values (i was having a couple of beers on the train too...but i'm a bit bamboozled , i'm sure its something idiotic and simple (aka really annoying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two markers that move through the list and keep track of sum of values between them. While current sum is less than target (13) and first marker is not at the end of the list move it forward and add value to current sum. Once first marker has been moved check if the current sum matches the target and update result accordingly. In final step move second marker forward one step and subtract item that it pointed to from current sum.

```
l = [5, 5, 3, 10, 2, 8, 10]
TARGET = 13
res = []
end = 0
current = 0

for start in range(len(l)):
    while current < TARGET and end < len(l):
        current += l[end]
        end += 1

    res.append(l[start:end] if current == TARGET else 'fail')

    current -= l[start]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 5, 3], 'fail', [3, 10], 'fail', 'fail', 'fail', 'fail']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your problem statement would benefit from rewriting as a sequence of small, self-contained, painfully obvious steps.

As far as I could understand, you take a list of numbers `xs` and look for values of `i` such that `xs[i] + xs[i + 1] == target`.

So, let's first generate a list of triples `(i, x[i], x[i + 1])`, then scan it for solutions.

An explicit way:

```
def pairs(xs):
  for i in range(len(xs) - 1):
    yield (i, xs[i], xs[i + 1])
```

A one-line way, fine for reasonably short lists:

```
def pairs(xs):
  return zip(range(len(xs)), xs, xs[1:])
```

Now find the matches:

```
matches = [(i, x0, x1) for (i, x0, x1) if x0 + x1 == target]
```

We don't mark the various conditions of mismatches, though. Tese can be added if the list comprehension above is converted into an explicit loop.

Hope this helps.